# SLIM Framework is not inserting Backbone model data to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, backbone.js, slim

I am using SLIM framework with backbone.js. My view is as like below

```
var book_view = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        el: $("body"),
        events:
        {
            "click #insert": "get_value"
        },      

        get_value: function()
        {          
            var data = {name: "sector", number: "12"};

            var book_model = new Book_model();   

            book_model.save(data,
            {
                success: function()
                {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    alert('error');
                }
            }); 
            return false;
        }
    });
```

My SLIM Framework POST Method is as like below

```
    <?php 
    require_once 'NotORM.php';
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=books;host=localhost','root');
    $db = new NotORM($pdo);
    require_once 'Slim/Slim.php';
    \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
    use \Slim\Slim;
    $app = new \Slim\Slim();

    $app->post("/book", function () use($app, $db) {
        $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        $book = $app->request()->post();
        $result = $db->books->insert($book);
        echo json_encode(array("id" => $result["id"]));
    });

    $app->run();
```

There is a table named book in my database.But my data is not saving in database.I think the problem is in SLIM framework PHP Code. What can be the problem ??

Comment: What does your Backbone model look like? Have you checked your browser developer tools to see what AJAX call is being made? Have you checked your server logs to see if the request is being handled?

Comment: I tested my code with another php script and it was working. I think problem is in PHP Code (SLIM Framework).